# How to connect a server url to sqlite3 in python

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to connect my server url to my sqlite3.I am not able to connect.

```
import sqlite3

connection = sqlite3.connect("http://{Servername}/python/mydatabase.db") # I am hiding my server name 

crsr = connection.cursor()

crsr.execute("SELECT * FROM data")
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: as I know `sqlite3` was created only to work with local files. You may have to download database from server to use it. And if you run code on this server then you need path to file not URL.

Comment: Is there any way to access online server .db files.

Comment: you would have to run SQL server like MySQL, Maria, etc. And it should be configured to access from external computer. Many SQL servers are configured to work only with code installed on server (using IP `127.0.0.1`) - for security reason. Sometimes the only method is to install web server and access database using web page - like PHPMyAdmin - but it is can't run Python script and it is useful only for some small changes in database.

Comment: Eventually you can create web page with API to database - ie. using Flask or Fast API or Hugs - but this will run some functions using `requests` and server will have to use this information to run SQL querieson server. And this method uses some modern servers.